# Do matrices with only elements along the main and anti-diagonals have a name?

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, matrix-theory

To expand upon the title, I am wondering if there is a specific name for square matrices of the form:  $$M = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & & 0 & b_{1n} \\ 0 & a_{22} & 0 & \cdots & & b_{2 \ i} & & 0 \\ 0 & \ddots & \ddots & & \cdot^{\textstyle \cdot^{\textstyle \cdot}} & 0 & & 0 \\ & & & a_{} &  & \vdots  &  & \\ \vdots & 0 & \cdot^{\textstyle \cdot^{\textstyle \cdot}} & 0 & \ddots & 0 & & \vdots\\ & \cdots & b_{i \ n-(i+1)} & \cdots & & a_{i \ i} &\\ 0 & \cdot^{{\textstyle \cdot}^{\textstyle \cdot}} & & &  &  \ddots & \ddots & 0\\ b_{n 1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 & & \cdots & & a_{nn} \end{bmatrix} \\$$ 
where, $ M = A_{\text{diagonal}} + B_{\text{anti-diagonal}}$
Essentially, M is a square matrix which is zero everywhere except the main and anti-diagonals. In other words, it is the sum of diagonal and anti-diagonal square matrices with the same dimension.

Apologies for the formatting, the normal LaTeX notation for up-right dots is not supported on this site.

Comment: they have been called "X-matrices" in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2457192/87355); conjugation with a permutation matrix brings them into a block-diagonal form (2x2 blocks along the main diagonal), so you could just work in that representation.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker  Is every real (complex) matrix orthonormal (unitary) equivalent to  a  x  matrix?

Comment: @AliTaghavi -- I don't think so, because not every matrix has a complete set of two-dimensional invariant subspaces, for example $\tiny\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: +1 for the rising dots.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you for your comment. I was not aware of the post referring to them as X matrices which is a very fitting name; however, I was hoping for a more standard terminology that is perhaps present in the literature. I will keep looking and report back at a later date.

Comment: I would call them Confederate Flag matrices, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_display_of_the_Confederate_battle_flag#/media/File:Battle_flag_of_the_Confederate_States_of_America.svg

Comment: For goodness's sake do not call them Confederate Flag matrices. If you want flags with X designs, how about [Jamaica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Jamaica) or [Jersey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Jersey).

Comment: Or from heraldry, the [saltire](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saltire).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am continuing in the answer box, to get this out of the "unanswered" queue. The OP asks "for a more standard terminology that is perhaps present in the literature."

The name "X-matrices" or "X-form matrices" has also been used in the published literature, for example, [Properties of Central Symmetric X-Form Matrices](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236874314_Properties_of_Central_Symmetric_X-Form_Matrices) (2011) and [The exponential functions of central-symmetric X-form matrices](https://jmm.guilan.ac.ir/article_1804.html) (2016).

The reason, I guess, why this name is not used more extensively, is that it seems more natural to reorder the basis vectors and work with $2\times 2$ block-diagonal matrices.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this :) . I'll mark this as the answer since I was looking for the terminology in current literature.